# jqgrid common parameters of the Form Editing Dialogs. How?

Tags: jqgrid

I have to apply some common parameters of the Form Editing Dialogs defined in the pager.

Current pager is

```
.navGrid('#pager10', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, view: true },

    // Edit
        {},
    // Add
         {},
    // Delete
            {},

    //Search
            {},
    //View
        {}

         );
```

and I want to use below paramters on all the action like Add, Edit, Delete, View.

How I do this?

```
{mtype: "POST", closeOnEscape:true, drag: true, resize: true, jqModal: false,
 recreateForm: false, closeAfterEdit: true, closeAfterAdd: true,
 savekey: [true, 13], viewPagerButtons: false }
```

Comment: I don't receive any notification about your message. You should write the comment to one of my previous answer, then I will see the it (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work for more information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Together with `jQuery.jgrid.defaults` defines standard options of jqGrid there are `jQuery.jgrid.edit`, `jQuery.jgrid.view`, `jQuery.jgrid.del`, `jQuery.jgrid.nav` which you can use. The settings of `jQuery.jgrid.edit` are common for Add and Edit dialog.

For example,

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm: true,
    jqModal: false,
    closeAfterAdd: true,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeOnEscape:true,
    savekey: [true, 13]);
```

You can set in the same way some standard event handler which you plan use in all your grids.

You wrote in your question that you want set `mtype: "POST"`, `drag: true`, `resize: true` and some other values which are already default (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing)). I recommend you to verify which values are already default. Moreover I strictly recommend you to use `recreateForm: true` and not default `recreateForm: false` if you use any customizations or event binding of the dialogs.

Comment: When I use $.extend($.jgrid.view, { viewPagerButtons: false }); than viewPagerButton is gone but if I use      $.extend($.jgrid.defaults, { viewPagerButtons: false }); the viewPagerButton is still there. Any suggestion?

Comment: @pirzada: `$.jgrid.defaults` set defaults for **jqGrid settings** (see list http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events). Defaut values of `viewGridRow` used to deisplay View dialog of **form editing** are listed under http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties1 can be changed with `$.jgrid.view`