# Format jQgrid editable textbox height

Tags: css, jqgrid

I am using jQgrid version 4.6.0 (Free version) and trying to edit the height of textbox which gets rendered when we set `editable: true` in Column model. I want the textbox height to fit into complete grid cell.

[image]

Here the width of rendered textbox is fine and fits in the cell but how can I increase the `height` of textbox?

Trying to achieve:-

[image]

Comment: Which [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing) you use? (I mean [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing), [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) or [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing)). Do you want to increase the height of one specific textbox or you and to set the something like `height:100%` for all textboxes? Should be the font of the textbox be increased too or you want just have free space above and below "10"?

Comment: @Oleg - I am doing cell editing, and only two cells are editable. Yes I want all the editable textbox to cover complete cell as shown in updated screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some trick which you can use. You can `editoptions` in the column defined something like

```js
editoptions: { style: "height:40px;" }
```

It will set `style` attribute on the textbox creating during editing. I think that the trick will work for any editing mode which you will use.

**UPDATED:** One can do the following in case of usage cell editing:

```js
afterEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var tr = this.rows[iRow], h = $(tr).height(),
        $input = $(tr.cells[iCol]).find("input"),
        delta = $input.outerHeight() - $input.height();

    $input.height(h - delta);
}
```

Inside of the most callbacks `this` will be initialized to the DOM of the `<table>` element (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp)), which supports `rows` property to quick access to the row by `rowIndex` and the row (`<tr>`) supports [cells](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tablerow.asp) array which can be used to get the cell by cell index. The rest of the code should be clear I hope.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried this. But my cell height may vary based on the data so was thinking if we can inherit the cell's height or something.

Comment: @RahulSingh: You are welcome! See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Instead of giving the height in pixles I gave `height:100%;` and it is working as expected. Thank You :)

Comment: @RahulSingh: You are welcome! Be carefully,  `height:100%` will work not always. It depends on many factors. If you will have problems you can go back to fixed pixel height.