# jqGrid auto scroll breaks when columns support text wrap

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

After enabling the **auto scroll** feature, i.e. `scroll: 1`, AND enabling word wrap in columns of **jqGrid, v4.4.1**, the grid/table cannot scroll to the last records if the row height has changed due to text wrapping in 1 or more columns. If all rows use only a single line (no wrapping) then the auto scroll feature works great. If some rows use more than a single line (variable height rows throughout the table) then the auto scroll feature starts to break down. Most commonly this means that you cannot get to the last page of results because the grid has calculated the length of the vertical scroll bar incorrectly.

Style to support word wrapping:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
  font-weight: normal; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: pre-wrap !important; /* changed to enable word wrap */
  height: 22px;
  padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px; 
  border-bottom-color: inherit; 
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? At the moment I am turning off the text wrapping and just widening the columns.

Could `populateVisible` be modified to calculate the length of the vertical scroll bar differently? It seems to calculate based on the `height of the first row x num rows (line 852 of v4.4.1)`. I suspect that the answer is 'no', but ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer that I can think of is to set a fixed height for each td and still allow word wrapping. This isn't straight forward though:

1. Change the height in `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td`. (Probably need to replicate this style on `.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgroup td` if you are using that as well.)

   ```
   .ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
     font-weight: normal; 
     overflow: hidden; 
     white-space: pre;
     height: 42px; /* higher fixed height, default is 22px */
     padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
     border-bottom-width: 1px; 
     border-bottom-color: inherit; 
     border-bottom-style: solid;
   }
   ```
2. Use [Master Oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315935/oleg)'s solution to [restrict the maximum height of row in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574194/1123275). I.e. a custom formatter which wraps the content in the `td` with a `div`.

NOTE: in the end I am just using single lines at 22px (default), no wrapping and setting the cols a bit wider - quicker and still allows tooltips to show any hidden text.

Comment: Accepted as answer due to no other alternatives.