# How to manipulate the content of js jqgrid 1.7 row view window

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have somewhat large text fields in my DB, which I would like to include in my jqGrid.
Instead of making the grid messy and huge, I would like to place some kind of a placeholder instead of  this text field, let's say V or X, that would represent whether or not there is additional content available to view.

Then, after the user choices to view a certain row, a popup(standard jqGrid row view) in revealed before him, there he can read the entire textual content, and also view the information from the other columns beside it.

Now, my problems is as described below:

How can I dynamically refresh the content of this row from the DB upon request and place it in the right row in this popup except using direct manipulation the the HTML, which I suppose is somewhat dirty:

```
$('#v_recommendation_count').html('Oleg<br/>Is recommended<br/>Oleg<br/>Is recommended<br/>Oleg<br/>Is recommended');
```

Also how can I control the measures of this window?, not only the external ones, but also the row and col size, as it seems not fully responsive and part of the label row texts are overlay-ed into the content row.

Thanks in advance,
Oleg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should just use `max-height` property in some places of jqGrid. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6574194/315935), [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330814/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420646/315935) for more examples.