# How to add/edit rows of a jqgrid, using navigator, in client side before submitting the whole grid as a JSON to the controller?

Tags: json, ajax, jqgrid

I have a navigation grid, populated using the JSON data received from the controller.This data is stored as a JSON in database in single column.

```
    $('#list-grid').jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
        mtype: 'GET',
        postData: { parameter1: para1, parameter2:para2 },
        datatype: 'json',
        gridview: true,
        caption: ' ',
        height: '100%',
        multiselect: true,
        rowNum: 5000,
        viewrecords: true,
        //colmodel and colnames
     });
```

Now, I have added navigation bar to the grid.

```
jQuery("#list-grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#list-grid3-pager',
{ edit: true, add: true, del: true, refresh: true, search: false, view: false, refreshtitle: "Clear filters", edittitle: "Edit selected record", addtitle: "Add new record" },
{
  //this code executes on 'Submit' button in the dialog 
  //here, the selected row should be edited and edit should be reflected in the grid---in client-side
  //then the whole grid has to be serialized, 
  //one more parameters has to be added 
  //and finally posted to the controller
}//edit option
```

Using a separate AJAX call, with a separate 'Save' button, I could have done like following to send the grid data, although this grid would still not have newly edited/added data:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {

        var gridData = jQuery("#list-grid").getRowData();
        var postGridData = JSON.stringify(gridData);

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("MyAction2", "MyController")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ parameter1: para1,  gridValues: postGridData }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

            });
        }
```

**My Question:**
How do I add/edit rows in navigation grid, and after each add/edit `Submit` click, stringify the whole grid, (the added record should be there, and if any row has been edited, the string should contain the changed value and not the old one) , add a parameter and then pass it to the controller (just as you see in the ajax call)  ?

Comment: Please include the information about the version of jqGrid which you use (or can use) and the fork of jqGrid in **every question about jqGrid**. Different versions have *different features* and the solution of many problems is different too. If I correctly understand your problem, then the usage of `editurl: "clientArray"` should solve your problem. On the other side retro versions of jqGrid don't supports `editurl: "clientArray"` in form editing. It's important to know whether you use `loadonce: true` or not.

Comment: I am using version 4.5.2. I switched to inline edit. Now, since i have given `multiselect:true` , I need to get the ids of the selected rows on click of delete button, before submit, delete those rows from the client side only. How do i do it?

Comment: Just get `selarrrow` with respect of `getGridParam`.

Comment: But unlike `onclickSubmit` there is no `onclickDelete` to custom handle the local row deletion, when `Delete` is clicked from navbar of the grid

Comment: I can't follow you. What you mean under `onclickDelete`. If the user clicks Delete button of the navigator bar then `delGridRow` method will be called. The method has `beforeSubmit` and `onclickSubmit` callbacks which you can specify in `navGrid` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130790/discussion-between-b-g-and-oleg).

Comment: I think that you goes in absolutely false direction. Delete dialog calls `delRowData` automatically and it closes the dialog after that. You should of cause use `url: "clientArray"` instead of `url :''`, which is wrong. You try to solve the problems, which not exist in retro versions of jqGrid. I'm not sure, when exactly local deleting is implemented, but jqGrid 4.7 has definitively the feature. I recommend you don's spend time and just upgrade jqGrid, which you use.

Comment: @Oleg: I have posted a question related to beforeSubmit, could you please see the following link and help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211943/beforesubmit-event-isnt-added-to-the-jqgrid-4-5-2