# beforeSubmit event isn't added to the jqgrid-4.5.2

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid 4.5.2 version with Jquery-3.2.1. Not able to bind the beforeSubmit function to the jqgrid.

Below is the sample code to bind the event.

```
var config = {};
config.beforeSubmit = function(grid, postData, formid, frmoper){
   ....
}
if (config.beforeSubmit) {
    this.grid.off('jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit').on("jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit", config.beforeSubmit);
}
```

Would be thankful if someone could help me on this.

**Below is a brief explanation on how the beforeSubmit event is added in my application**

In my case we are overriding the jqgrid library with a DataGrid.js file. In this, I have a function named DataGrid.buildGrid = function(configXml, params, cb), which is called at run time and builds the grid dynamically. This function internally calls generateGrid().

```
DataGrid.buildGrid = function(configXml, params, cb) {
  ....
  ....
  var myGrid = new DataGrid(jqConfig, params);
  myGrid.generateGrid();
}
```

the below is the sample generateGrid() code:

```
DataGrid.prototype.generateGrid = function() {
  ...
  var jqConfig = DataGrid.getJqConfig(form, params, cb);
  ...
  this.bindConfigEvents();
}
```

in getJqConfig() we are adding the beforeSubmit event to jqConfig object

```
DataGrid.getJqConfig = function(form, options, cb) {
  var jqConfig = {};
  ....
  ....
  config.beforeSubmit = function(grid, postData, formid, frmoper){
  ....
}
```

in bindConfigEvents() function we are binding the beforeSubmit

```
DataGrid.prototype.bindConfigEvents = function() {
  ...
  ...
  if (this.jqConfig.beforeSubmit) {
    this.grid.off('jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit').on("jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit", this.jqConfig.beforeSubmit);
  }
}
```

Comment: `jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit` should work on the retro version 4.5.2, which you use. 4 years ago, at the time of publishing of jqGrid 4.5.2, the latest version of jQuery was 1.10.3. One included jQuery 1.4.3 as the part of jqGrid 4.5.2. It could be that jqGrid 4.5.2 has problems with jQuery 3.2.1. In any way, you should post more clean code example. Your current code shows just that you try to use jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit event, but it's unclear *when* you bind the event to the grid or to the table. The context of the usage is unclear.

Comment: @Oleg: I have updated the question with brief explanation on implementation of jqgrid on my application. Could you please go through and ask if anything is missing in it.

Comment: Personally I think that your code is a little bit complex. What I can recommend you is: Be a sure that the grid is created and then after that manually add the following code: `$("#grid").bind('jqGridAddEditBeforeSubmit', function(...){...});` . See the result

Comment: @TonyTomov: Could you please sugggst whether I need to add it in loadComplete or somewhere else

Comment: @santoshM, loadComplete is very bad option. Usually you can call this command after `$('#grid').jqGrid(...);` Be a sure the editRow is called too either as separate method or through navigator - navGrid in order this to have effect. Another note - do not forget that this event should return array of type [boolean success, text error] - see docs in the jqGrid wiki